# Calculating amount of parallelism of a schedule

Tags: algorithm, graph

We have a parallel scheduling system which works this way

There are N parallel processes ( or agents ) that each compute 1 task at a time till its completion without any preemption

We have an event log that has the start & end times of each tasks. Tasks are grouped into jobs and we have several jobs running in parallel. Jobs don't depend on each other and tasks within a job can ALL run in parallel at the same time

What happens is that, if we increase the number of jobs, then the net parallelism of a job is reduced or rather, major chunk of tasks of a job get executed nearly serially

e.g. IF I have 10 processes and 10 jobs with 10 tasks each, then each job will run on just 1 process effectively making all the jobs run serially

I want to quantify this information, and I am not sure what is the best way to do so. Perhaps what I want is to **quantify resource contention**

Some ideas that were in my mind was

**1. Create a graph of tasks per job**

There is a directed edge between two tasks T1 and T2 if `T1.end < T2.start`

Then, the amount of tasks that were executed serially would be the longest path in this directed graph

Do you see any concern with this approach. Is there a better way to model this?

**2. Time to start a task**

For each task, I calculate `task.start - job.start`. But then again, what information is this data providing?

Comment: Indeed, a simple model for that would be `ceil(task_count/N)*avg_task_time`. But if tasks vary in times dramatically, do you propose any other model?

Comment: I do not understand what your formula means.  What is N?  What has the average task time have to do with anything?

Comment: Oh I thought when you mentioned "every job had run in ||el", I thought you asked me to consider the maximum parallelism N ( number of processes ) into account. What you are effectively saying is not to consider the limitation of number of processes

What would be a perfect time for a job with 5 task with following completion time: 1s,1s,1s,1s,10s

Comment: I am not entirely clear from your question but it seems that the tasks within a job may run in ||el.  So the perfect job time is for that job is 10 seconds.  Please confirm that tasks in a job may run in }}el.

Comment: yes, all tasks can run in parallel and have no dependency between them

Comment: In that case, the job is completely irrelevant.  The system can be considered as a collection of tasks, without the need to consider the jobs at all.  Each task can be assigned  the earliest possible start time of the job, and then the jobs can be forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple metric: calculate how long it would have taken if every job had run in ||el ( i.e. there were an infinite number of processors ). This is the "perfect time" Subtract "perfect" from how long it actually took to complete every job. Divide by the "perfect" time and express as a per cent. This is a metric of how much contention occurred.

First, let's look at the perfect job completion time: since all the tasks can run in parallel this is the maximum of the task durations in the job.

If all the jobs start at the same time, then the perfect time for ALL jobs is simply the longest perfect job time.

If the jobs start at different times, then you have to calculate the maximum value of job start time + job perfect time.

Perfect job time job j

```
PJT(j) = MAX( td(t) ) for all tasks in j
```

Perfect time

```
PT = MAX( starttime(j) + PJT(j) ) for all j
```

Contention metric

```
C = 100 * (actual time of completion of all jobs - PT ) / PT
```

Basic example:

```
3 jobs 1 task each duration 10 secs
2 processors available
Actual time is 20 secs
Perfect time is 10 secs
Contention is 100%

4 jobs 1 task each duration 10 secs
2 processors available
Actual time is 20 secs
Perfect time is 10 secs
Contention is 100%
```

---

**Task Delayed Metric**

```
TDM = 100 * number of tasks delayed / total number of tasks
```

Basic example:

```
3 jobs 1 task each duration 10 secs
2 processors available
1 task is delayed
TDM is 33%

4 jobs 1 task each duration 10 secs
2 processors available
2 tasks delayed
TDM is 50%
```

---

**Metric comparison**

The contention metric gives a measure of the total delay be all the jobs considered as one.  The TDM gives a better measure of the delays experienced by individual tasks.  Which one is used depends on what you are most interested in: overall delay or individual task delay.

Comment: I'm a little unsure of the perfect time of the job. Let's just consider there was 1 job with 1000 tasks and 10 processors. Each task took 1s, then according to your logic the perfect time is 1000s. Isn't addition of all task duration effectively making it serial? Shouldn't perfect time of a job be 1s since every task ran in parallel ( assuming infinite processors )

Comment: So, in a infinite # of processor this job ran for 1s. with 10 processors, this job ran for 100sec

Comment: In your example, wouldn't contention be just 33% ? i.e. out of 3 tasks, only 1 task could not run immediately. What's your definition of contention?

Comment: I define my contention metric in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: There are many different metrics that could be defined.  The number of tasks delayed over the total number of tasks would also be an interesting metric.

Comment: Your metric would be a little harder to compute.  You would need to look at the perfect start time and the actual start time of each task.

Comment: I like your points and I have a clear understanding of what I want. Overall delay is good, but I also care about contention per job and for that I am settling for the following `sum(t.start - j.start ) for all task in j / sum(t.end - j.start ) for all task in j`

Comment: Indeed, an overall load avg like metric e..g `pending tasks / Number of processes` is also a good proxy into the amount of demand if i want to take into account Number of processes

Comment: "Number of processes"?  Perhaps you mean number of processors?

Comment: I do not understand your formula.  It seems to apply to just one job.  Surely you want something for all the tasks in all the jobs?

Comment: a global and local metric per job sounds good

Comment: A per job metric does not make much sense.  The tasks in a job are delayed, or not, when they "lose" contention for processors with other tasks, perhaps tasks in other jobs.  Since there is no priority scheme it is random whether a task is delayed or not so the only metrics that make sense measure the behavious of the entire system. not just individual tasks.